# Colorir campo select option chosen

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Tenho um campo select option e gostaria que ao usuário clicasse em submeter, o sistema colorisse o campo

Ao inspecionar o elemento com o chrome percebi que o chosen colocar um style display: none e se tirar ele funciona, mas não é isso o que eu quero:

O objeto é caso estiver vazio quando clicar no botão, o select option ficar vermelho

Segue exemplo:

```js
var setores = [
            "Almoxarifado",
            "Controladoria",
            "Administrativo",
            "Tecnologia de Informação" 
  ];
 
 var i = 0;
 setores.forEach(function(item){
    i++;
    addOption(i, item);
});

function addOption(i, valor) {
    var option = new Option(valor, i );
    var select = document.getElementById("cmb-setor");
    select.add(option);
}

$('#cmb-setor').trigger("chosen:updated");
  
$('.btn-save').on('click', function(){
   var id = $('#cmb-setor').val();
   console.log("Setor: "+id);
   if( id == 0 ){
     $('select[id="cmb-setor"]').css("border-color","red");
  //   $('select[id="cmb-setor"]').css({"border-color":"red", "display":"block"});
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
   <select class=" form-control" id="cmb-setor" data-placeholder="Escolha um setor">
       <option value="0"></option>
   </select>
</div> 

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Salvar</button>


<script>
   $('#cmb-setor').chosen( {allow_single_deselect: true} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando mudar a borda do *select* sendo que o *Chosen* oculta o *select* e cria uma *div* no lugar, então você deve alterar a borda da *div*, para isso criaremos um estilo *required*.

Em vez de tentar alterar a borda do *select*:

```
$('select[id="cmb-setor"]').css("border-color","red");
```

Altere da *div* que foi criada pelo *Chosen*:

```
// div[class='chosen-container-single']
$('div.chosen-container-single').addClass('required');
```

Crie um estilo no *CSS*:

```
.required .chosen-single {
    border: 1px solid #EE0000 !important;
}
```

#### Veja como ficou

```js
var setores = [
            "Almoxarifado",
            "Controladoria",
            "Administrativo",
            "Tecnologia de Informação" 
  ];
 
 var i = 0;
 setores.forEach(function(item){
    i++;
    addOption(i, item);
});

function addOption(i, valor) {
    var option = new Option(valor, i );
    var select = document.getElementById("cmb-setor");
    select.add(option);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cmb-setor').trigger("chosen:updated");
  $('#cmb-setor').chosen({
    allow_single_deselect: true
  });
  
  $('.btn-save').on('click', function(){
    var id = $('#cmb-setor').val();
    console.log("Setor: "+id);
    if( id == 0 ){
      // Adiciona a classe "required" na div atraves do seletor "class"
      $('div.chosen-container-single').addClass('required');
    } else {
      // Remove a classe "required" na div atraves do seletor "class"
      $('div.chosen-container-single').removeClass('required');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.required .chosen-single {
    border: 1px solid #EE0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
   <select class=" form-control" id="cmb-setor" data-placeholder="Escolha um setor">
       <option value="0"></option>
   </select>
</div> 

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: E se no caso tiver mais de um combobox ,como seria?

Comment: Estou tentando assim : `$('#cmb-setor.chosen-container-single').addClass('required');` e não está funcionando

Comment: Descobri! Dentro da classe  `choosen-container` o chosen adiciona um texto a mais na id. Sendo assim fica `id=cmb-setor_chosen` a partir daí ficaria $('#cmb-setor_chosen').addClass('required')‌​; Valeu